# `doto` for Scala

Tags: scala

Clojure offers a macro called `doto` that takes its argument and a list of functions and essentially calls each function, prepending the (evaluated) argument:

```
(doto (new java.util.HashMap) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2))
-> {a=1, b=2}
```

Is there some way to implement something similar in Scala? I envision something with the following form:

```
val something =
  doto(Something.getInstance) {
    x()
    y()
    z()
  }
```

which will be equivalent to

```
val something = Something.getInstance
something.x()
something.y()
something.z()
```

Might it be possible using `scala.util.DynamicVariable`s?

Note that with factory methods, like `Something.getInstance`, it is not possible to use the common Scala pattern

```
val something =
  new Something {
    x()
    y()
    z()
  }
```

Comment: As a side-note, this question is a dup. I can't find the original, however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing built-in in the library but you can mimic it quite easily:

```
def doto[A](target: A)(calls: (A => A)*) =
  calls.foldLeft(target) {case (res, f) => f(res)}
```

Usage:

```
scala> doto(Map.empty[String, Int])(_ + ("a" -> 1), _ + ("b" ->2))
res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> doto(Map.empty[String, Int])(List(_ + ("a" -> 1), _ - "a", _ + ("b" -> 2)))
res10: Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 2)
```

Of course, it works as long as your function returns the proper type. In your case, if the function has only side effects (which is not so "scalaish"), you can change `doto` and use `foreach` instead of `foldLeft`:

```
def doto[A](target: A)(calls: (A => Unit)*) =
  calls foreach {_(target)}
```

Usage:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.{Map => M}
import collection.mutable.{Map=>M}

scala> val x = M.empty[String, Int]
x: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map()

scala> doto(x)(_ += ("a" -> 1), _ += ("a" -> 2))

scala> x
res16: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 2)
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I did not think to use a fold. Wonders of functional programming...

Comment: Beware, once again, according to your example, the `fold` version won't fit and you'll have to stick to the `foreach`version

Comment: As I commented to @unknown user, I'm trying to use this pattern to initialize objects in the standard Java library, specifically a `java.net.URLConnection` returned by a `java.net.HttpConnection.openConnection`. The API was not designed with chaining in mind. Unfortunately, when interfacing to the standard library APIs, and trying to write in a functional style, kludges are frequently necessary.

Comment: If you use varargs rather than taking a `TraversableOnce` you can cut out the `List(...)` at your call site. Also `x` can be a `val`

Comment: And in your `doto` call you don't need the type annotation

Comment: In the second case, yes. In the first one, I'd have to explicit the type of `Map.empty` which almost the same.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala, the "typical" way to do this would be to chain "tap" or "pipe" methods.  These are not in the standard library, but are frequently defined as so:

```
implicit class PipeAndTap[A](a: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
  def tap[B](f: A => B): A = { f(a); a }
}
```

Then you would

```
(new java.util.HashMap[String,Int]) tap (_.put("a",1)) tap (_.put("b",2))
```

This is not as compact as the Clojure version (or as compact as Scala can be), but it is about as close to canonical as one is likely to get.

<sup>(Note: if you want to minimize run-time overhead for adding these methods, you can make `a` a `private val` and have `PipeAndTap` extend `AnyVal`; then this will be a "value class" which is only converted into a real class when you need an object to pass around; just calling a method doesn't actually require class creation.)</sup>

<sup>(Second note: in older versions of Scala, `implicit class` does not exist.  You have to separately write the class and an `implicit def` that converts a generic `a` to a `PipeAndTap`.)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I think, that the closest would be to import this object's members in scope:

```
val something = ...
import something._

x()
y()
z()
```

In this post you can find another example (in section "Small update about theoretical grounds"):

http://hacking-scala.posterous.com/side-effecting-without-braces

---

Also small advantage with this approach - you can import individual members and rename them:

```
import something.{x, y => doProcessing}
```

Answer (score 1):

More simple I guess:

```
val hm = Map [String, Int] () + ("a"-> 1) + ("b"-> 2)
```

Your sample

```
val something =
  doto (Something.getInstance) {
    x()
    y()
    z()
  }
```

doesn't look very functional, because - what is the result? I assume you're side effecting.

```
Something.x().y().z()
```

could be a way if each call produces the type where the next function can act on.

```
z(y(x(Something)))
```

another kind of producing a result.

And there is the `andThen` method to chain method calls on collections, you might want to have a look at.

For your Map-example, a fold-left is another way to go:

```
val hm = Map [String, Int] () + ("a"-> 1) + ("b"-> 2) 

val l = List (("a", 8), ("b", 7), ("c", 9))
(hm /: l)(_ + _)
// res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 8, b -> 7, c -> 9)
```

Comment: It's not very functional, but then again, neither is the Java standard library. The example applies to many of the functions in the library, like initializing a Swing component, a URL connection (obtained from an HttpConnection), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can think of two ways of doing it: passing strings as parameters, and having a macro change the string and compile it, or simply importing the methods. If Scala had untyped macros, maybe they could be used as well -- since it doesn't have them, I'm not going to speculate on it.

At any rate, I'm going to leave macro alternatives to others. Importing the methods is rather simple:

```
val map = collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]()
locally {
  import map._
  put("a", 1)
  put("b", 2)
}
```

Note that `locally` doesn't do anything, except restrict the scope in which the members of `map` are imported.

Answer (score 0):

One very basic way to chain several actions is function composition:

```
val f:Map[Int,String]=>Map[Int,String] = _ + (1 -> "x")
val g:Map[Int,String]=>Map[Int,String] = _ + (2 -> "y")
val h:Map[Int,String]=>Map[Int,String] = _ + (3 -> "z")

(h compose g compose f)(Map(42->"a"))
// Map[Int,String] = Map((42,a), (1,x), (2,y), (3,z))
```

In this case it's not very practical, though, as the type of the functions can't be inferred easily...